# Is there a method to evaluate functions with different input values?

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
  A1= c(a=10,b=5,c=4)
  A2= c(a=5,b=6,c=4)
  A3= c(a=1,b=2,c=3)
```

The function is:

```
 y=a+exp(b+1)-c
```

I want to get the following table when I substitute the values of  A1, A2, A3 in the function.

```
yA1 409.42
yA2 1097.63
yA3 18.08
```

Please advise if you require further information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easier to accomplish if you store your variables as lists, and then use `sapply`:

```
vars <- list(
  A1= list(a=10,b=5,c=4),
  A2= list(a=5,b=6,c=4),
  A3= list(a=1,b=2,c=3)
)

y <- sapply(vars, function(x) with(x, a+exp(b+1)-c))

        A1         A2         A3 
 409.42879 1097.63316   18.08554
```

And your desired format:

```
data.frame(yA = names(y), value = y, row.names = NULL)

  yA      value
1 A1  409.42879
2 A2 1097.63316
3 A3   18.08554
```

You can also do a more succinct version with `expr` and `eval`:

```
my_formula <- expr( a+exp(b+1)-c )
y <- sapply(vars, eval, expr = my_formula)

        A1         A2         A3 
 409.42879 1097.63316   18.08554
```

Comment: Thank you, is it possible to have the names for each column, For example, yA and values?